# Can I see the list of my upvoted comments?

Tags: discussion

I put [a lot of comments](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/20122/zistoloen?tab=activity&sort=comments) on questions and answers. I would like to know the list of comments which have been upvoted (score >= 1) by a member of the community. I don't want to know who has upvoted the comments.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution exists on `data.stackexchange.com` [on this webpage](http://data.stackexchange.com/webmasters/query/104649/upvoted-comments).

The proposed request returns precisely the list of all upvoted comments with associated score. It just needs to choose user and StackExchange website.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `data.stackexchange.com`. It's not in real time but it has a ton of data for easy mining.

Comment: Thank you for the trail.